# Syntax error 'date' field on custom account.move - Odoo v8

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8

I have this method:

```
@api.multi
@api.depends('order_picking', 'order_picking.isbn', 'contract_worksheet', 'state')
def accounting_scenarios(self):
    for record in self:
        if not len(record.transporter):
            raise Warning('Please Enter Transporter !')
        elif not len(record.transporter.transp_transit):
            raise Warning('Please assign transit account to the transporter !')
        if record.state in ('awaitingraw'): 
            record.temp = record.contract_worksheet.total_alles - record.contract_worksheet.total_totals
            acc_move = self.env['account.move'] 
            move_lines = [
                (0, 0, {
                    'name': 'name', 
                    'debit': record.temp, 
                    'credit': 0, 
                    'account_id': record.transporter.transp_transit, 
                    'date': date,
                    'partner_id': record.transporter, 

                }),
            ]

            journal_id = False
            if record.transporter.property_account_payable:
                journals = self.env['account.journal'].search([
                    ('default_debit_account_id', '=', record.transporter.property_account_payable.id)
                ])
                if journals:
                    journal_id = journals[0].id
            acc_move.create({
                    'journal_id': journal_id, 
                    'date':date,
                    'state': 'draft',
                    'line_id': move_lines, 
                })
        elif record.state in ('work_in_progress'):
            record.temp2 = record.contract_worksheet.total_totals
        elif record.state in ('delivered'):
            record.transporter.transp_transit.debit = record.contract_worksheet.total_alles
```

Whenever I try to creaet (or change to the `awaitingraw`) state, it throws me this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\.\openerp\http.py", line 546, in _handle_exception
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\.\openerp\http.py", line 583, in dispatch
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\.\openerp\http.py", line 319, in _call_function
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\.\openerp\service\model.py", line 118, in wrapper
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\.\openerp\http.py", line 316, in checked_call
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\.\openerp\http.py", line 812, in __call__
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\.\openerp\http.py", line 412, in response_wrap
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\openerp\addons\web\controllers\main.py", line 948, in call_button
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\openerp\addons\web\controllers\main.py", line 936, in _call_kw
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\.\openerp\api.py", line 268, in wrapper
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\.\openerp\api.py", line 399, in old_api
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\openerp\addons\bsi\models\models.py", line 1472, in check_quantity
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\.\openerp\api.py", line 266, in wrapper
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\openerp\addons\bsi\models\models.py", line 1400, in write
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\.\openerp\api.py", line 266, in wrapper
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\.\openerp\models.py", line 3789, in write
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\.\openerp\api.py", line 266, in wrapper
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\.\openerp\api.py", line 592, in new_api
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\.\openerp\models.py", line 4048, in _write
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\.\openerp\api.py", line 266, in wrapper
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\.\openerp\models.py", line 5773, in recompute
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\.\openerp\models.py", line 5773, in <dictcomp>
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\.\openerp\models.py", line 5654, in __getitem__
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\.\openerp\fields.py", line 835, in __get__
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\.\openerp\fields.py", line 913, in determine_value
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\.\openerp\fields.py", line 893, in compute_value
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\.\openerp\fields.py", line 885, in _compute_value
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\.\openerp\api.py", line 266, in wrapper
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\openerp\addons\bsi\models\models.py", line 1390, in accounting_scenarios
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\.\openerp\api.py", line 266, in wrapper
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\.\openerp\api.py", line 508, in new_api
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\openerp\addons\account\account.py", line 1388, in create
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\.\openerp\api.py", line 268, in wrapper
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\.\openerp\api.py", line 372, in old_api
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\.\openerp\models.py", line 4101, in create
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\.\openerp\api.py", line 266, in wrapper
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\.\openerp\api.py", line 508, in new_api
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\.\openerp\models.py", line 4245, in _create
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\.\openerp\sql_db.py", line 171, in wrapper
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\.\openerp\sql_db.py", line 247, in execute
DataError: la sintaxis de entrada no es vÃ¡lida para tipo date: Â«<type 'datetime.date'>Â»
LINE 1: ...account_move_id_seq'), '/', 1, NULL, 'draft', 13, '<type ''d...
                                                         ^
```

So, the offending line is this one `'date': date,` on both cases, so, how can I overcome this? Should I just put `'date'` between `''`?

I'm not sure, or maybe a delta to take the actual date, I've seen something like this `'date': fields.Date.today(),` but I'm not sure...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to use an integer to set a date field. You can either use `fields.Date.today()` as you mentioned or convert your integer to a date using `strptime`.

```
datetime.datetime.strptime('2017-12-11', '%Y-%m-%d')
```

Comment: Thank You very much, indeed fields.Date.today() works!